# Why doesn't Python require exactly four spaces per indentation level?

Tags: python, indentation

Whitespace is signification in Python in that code blocks are defined by their indentation.

Furthermore, Guido van Rossum recommends using four spaces per indentation level (see [PEP 8: Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).

**What was the reasoning behind not requiring exactly four spaces per indentation level as well? Are there any technical reasons?**

It seems like all the arguments that can be made for making whitespace define code blocks can also be used to argument for setting an exact whitespace length for one indentation level (say four spaces).

Comment: Why restrict? Python is never a language to limit the programmer.

Comment: Xavier: Isn't that a Perl argument? :-) From "The Zen of Python": "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."

Comment: There is no down-votes for comments, so I will say :) My dream is not only four spaces requirement, but also requirement to name `functions_in_lower_case`, classes in `PascalCase`, etc. To support special cases something like `from __legacy__ import anynames` could exist.

Comment: What about the sods like us who like tab?!

Comment: @knorv: Python likes intuition, and readability. Clean codes are discovered, just like design patterns. They're good to know, but not enforced. Python is designed in a way to help that - that is, to be as consistent as possible. But I'm going to post a quick answer now.

Comment: @Pharaun: The only reason tabs are bad (that I know of) is because they don't print consistently on the web. They tend to print to 8 spaces long - and looks different if your IDE uses 4 spaces for tab length. Most IDEs today support tabs inserting 4 spaces instead - check it out.

Comment: Xavier: But they don't normally support jumping over 4 spaces with one arrow keypress. It wouldn't be consistent anyways. Besides I like to use tabs and display them 3 characters-long. Fortunately you can just guess the format on load and change to tabs, then change back to spaces when saving.

Comment: @Xavier: I know the whole space thing makes sense for web/etc but I use VIM, and i like to set my tab space to 2 or 4 spaces depending on what i am doing, so I just like the flexibility that tabs presents.

Comment: @viraptor, @Pharaun: Fair points!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are no technical reasons.  It would not be too hard to modify the Python interpreter to require exactly four spaces per indentation level.

Here is one use case for other indentation levels: when typing into the interactive interpreter, it's very handy to use one-space indentations.  It saves on typing, it's easier to count the number of spaces correctly, and readability is not a major concern (since the code isn't even saved in a file).

Answer (score 11):

Another case that I just encountered on the tutor@python.org mailing list - A blind programmer who is working in Python uses a reader program - apparently the reader program isn't terribly fond of multiple spaces, so it's easier on him to use a single space.

There's really no good or technical reason to require exactly 4 spaces, and I think the best argument against *requirement* is that programmers hate to be restricted, especially by stupid and somewhat arbitrary rules. Sure we all agree that 4 spaces is best and most of us have editors automagically set our indentation, but on the occasions you don't want to use 4 spaces - one off script code, etc. - you have now alienated a programmer who feels the crushing hand of an arbitrary (style) requirement.

The importance of whitespace isn't a problem for most people for a few reasons. First, I can't think of a single (good) programmer who would argue that proper code formatting is a bad thing. Second, logic requires us to separate our code into blocks. Many languages use {} delimiters. In assembly it's usually labels. Python's choice of whitespace is actually fairly natural, at least for the English language. When you read a book, or a newspaper, or a blog post, when someone makes a quote it's usually indented. Paragraphs are separated by a blank line or two. Chapters are usually separated by blank space at the end of a page and blank space at the beginning of the next. So whitespace is a good thing, but forcing programmers to adhere to *your* particular standard will get programmers to go do something else with their time.

Comment: If Python required 4 spaces (or 7, or whatever), we wouldn't even need this discussion.  Avoiding style discussions by imposing a language style is therefor a good thing.  As you said: an apt programmer can read 7 space indent code as well as 4 space indent code, so why not force everyone to use 4?

Comment: I never thought about that issue. Has he/she made a script to convert 4-space indent to 1-space indent, and forth? I'd imagine hearing "space space sapce space def class..." would be annoying.

Comment: @Xavier: Yeah, he does - I can't remember if it's a script or he just uses an editor feature, though.

Comment: It's really nice to hear about stories like this. I remember another member here on SO has trouble typing becaues of pain on his fingers, so he uses and has trained Dragon NaturallySpeaking to do the coding. Apparently it's been working out very well.

Comment: @Xavier: I always enjoy hearing about people who are considered "disabled" working with their physical/mental limitations to enjoy activities many of us take for granted. If I ever end out in academia I'm sure I'll focus a lot of research in that area.

Answer (score 8):

See [PEP 666 - Reject Foolish Indentation](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0666/)

Answer (score 6):

Using 1 space (or tab) saves space while code-golfing :-p

Answer (score 5):

Joel's [Best Software Writing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590595009) antology starts with Ken Arnold's interesting and provocative essay "Style is Substance", from Ken's post you can also read [here](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=74230).  It's a well-argued essay with the thesis, and I quote, that "the only way to get from where we are to a place where we stop worrying about style is to enforce it as part of the language".

It's the only essay I've ever read that proposes that languages' compilers should lock down *every* aspect of style (your idea about locking down amount of indentation, for example, would be part of that -- not just in Python, either... Ken's main past contributions are Jini, curses, javaspaces, rogue, and parts of Corba, nothing Python-related).  It makes really good points, and in the online version's comments you can see some counterpoints (alas, not necessarily equally well argued).

I do find it ironic that one responder talks about "Fortran and its strong formatting rules"; that sounds like somebody who never used Fortran, or used it with very shallow and marginal understanding of it.  How many languages do you know where you can write, for example,

```
total count = 1 000 000
```

...?  In Fortran, you can!  The spaces are irrelevant, and ignored by the compiler, inside both identifiers and number literals, so you don't have to use underscores or camelcase to make multiword identifiers usable (just use spaces between words!) and it's easy to make large numbers readable too.  Some languages did adopt this kind of rules, but most forbid spaces within identifiers and numbers.

Of course style flexibility always comes with risks of errors, e.g., in Fortran's case,

```
DO 10 I = 1. 5
```

assigns to variable `DO10I` the number 1.5, while the almost-undistinguishable

```
DO 10 I = 1, 5
```

loops five times on the block from here to line 10 (I believe a real-world occurrence of a bug like this one -- dot instead of comma drastically changing the code's meaning -- once damaged a space mission, but don't recall the exact details).

So, please don't take Fortran as an example either for or against "locking down", because in many stylistic aspects it's so incredibly *loose* instead!

Some examples of lockdown include modern languages that take e.g. case conventions and make them enforced parts of the language (uppercase initials for classes, etc) -- I believe Ruby at least warns about this and some other languages actually give compiler errors if you (e.g.) name a class with a lowercase initial or a non-class with an uppercase one.  I think the resulting enforced uniformity is a good thing, and I don't see why it should be different where the enforced aspect of style is spacing rather than casing, etc.  IOW, Arnold has mostly convinced me about this;-).

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740116/for-what-reason-do-we-have-the-lower-case-with-underscores-naming-convention/1740152#1740152 you argue eloquently against case sensitivity. So would you prefer Python to have style-lockdown, where that style is allcaps (or all lowercase)?

Comment: @unutbu, in practice I do have to program in a specific capitalization style (at work: we have and enforce style guides), and while I wouldn't find ALL CAPS ALL THE TIME any more readable than it was back in early Fortran, lowercase_with_underscores I would find preferable to CamelCaseStuff (which is Google's style for classes and functions).  It's all pretty hypothetical anyway, of course;-).

Answer (score 1):

While there are implications made by requiring consistent indentation within a single block, there are *no* implications made by having indentation levels between blocks be either the same or different. In other words, what would be the point?

Comparing it to the whitespace requirement isn't really valid because whitespace is a part of the syntax of Python: it defines scope. So long as scope can be unambiguously defined, why do we care how many spaces are used to define it? What benefit would be offered by forcing everyone to use some (completely arbitrary) fixed number of spaces?

What if your word processor forced you to indent paragraphs exactly four spaces? It would be annoying, and it would serve no purpose. It *shouldn't* serve a purpose to have a fixed number of spaces of indentation.

Think about it this way: Python doesn't have a 'whitespace' requirement so much as it has a requirement that you find a way to define scope without braces. What fell out of that was whitespace, and saying it has a 'whitespace requirement' is easier and more obvious than saying it has a 'scope definition sans braces' requirement, so for purposes of succinct communication, we just say it has a 'whitespace requirement' ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Python is all about rapid prototyping. A lot of the good designs only work because most Python programmers have good practices. That's why we don't depend on accessors and mutators as much as Java, and we can access array indices with negative numbers.

In my opinion, limiting the whitespaces to 4 and disallowing tabs doesn't make Python more readable on a large-scale. For a long time, there has been very few issues, because of the good practices we advocate.

I truly believe it.

**Python comes with convenience.**

Answer (score 1):

[reindent.py](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Tools/scripts/reindent.py) changes any python file to use 4-space indents and no hard tab characters.
Having this handy utility around obviates the need to force others to program
Python in the 4-space style.

PS. Perl, Java, C programmers spend many brain cycles fussing with semicolon syntax errors. Every brain cycle wasted on syntax fluff is a cycle not spend solving real programming problems. One of Python's advantages for rapid development is that it minimizes syntax rules that end up wasting brain cycles. Therefore fewer syntax requirements are better than more.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your answer. If you reindent the file to 4-space indents, you actually do force people looking at the source after you to work with 4-space indents... Unless you change it back before committing.

Comment: @viraptor: There are tools (like `unexpand`) which convert spaces to tabs. So if someone really wanted to work with tab-indented python, they have a way to do so too.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the reasons given above there's another really good reason why you'd want the interpreter to support minimal indentation: Saving space.  Due to the limitations of freezing Python bytecode it isn't always practical to ship something with just .pyc files instead of the actual code.  This means that if you're writing code to run on a a platform with very limited space (say, an OpenWRT router) it makes a lot of sense to keep the number of spaces to a minimum to save disk space.

This is why I wrote [pyminifier](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576704-python-code-minifier/)

Answer (score 0):

Python is already different than other languages in the way whitespace and line breaks are so significant. It's a unique part of the language and is very clean to work with of course, but I think to add this restriction would reduce flexibility.

Also, I like two spaces.... I'd be forced to write my programs with two spaces and then run them through a space doubler script as a compile step.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the problems that occur with `make`'s requirement to have tab characters in-front of each action.

For example It is a pain if you have tab equals four spaces and you're flicking back and forth from a `.c` file and a `Makefile`